# Can't get div to wrap around my header. Can anyone see why?

Tags: html, css, navigation, word-wrap

For the life of me I can't see why my "div" will not wrap around the header... I've closed it, the height is not specified...

I've searched other posts and no solutions so far. Is there a conflict that I'm overlooking?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <div id="siteLogo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="images/some image in a folder"/></a>        

    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#menu li a:hover { 
    color: #ff9900;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff9900;
}

#siteLogo img{
    height:auto;
    width: 220px;
}

#menu {
font-family: 'Comfortaa', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #c0c0c0;
    }

#outer {
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#wraper {
    width: 900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#navcontainer {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: thick 1px #ffppoo;
}

#siteLogo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: auto;
}

#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: auto;
}

#menu ul li {
    display:inline;
}

#menu ul {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li a {
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps to add borders on html elements so you can see the block layout. If you use firefox this browser plugin also might help https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tilt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight change to your syntax and containing/clearing your `float`s:

```
#navcontainer {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSfrb/

Comment: Bingo! got the div to encompass the menu. Thanks!... just one thing though, the navigation list still won't float: right any idea why?

Comment: In your code you have  `#menu` nested inside `#siteLogo` updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xSfrb/10/ if you move it to be alongside `#menu` then it floats right - http://jsfiddle.net/raJj8/

Comment: Well duh. Ha! don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks a tonne, David!

Comment: It's so easy to miss stuff like this, especially if you've been wracking your brains for ages. Fresh pair of eyes and all that.

Answer (score 0):

The floats are probably killing you. Try adding one last

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

before closing the navContainer

Answer (score 0):

The child elements are floating within a non-floating parent which causes the so-called **zero-height container problem** and has several solutions.

You can use overflow, like David Randall suggests

You can use an empty clear:both div, like Federico Jacobi suggests

Another solution is 'Clearfix', which uses pseudo content elements. See this related thread [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) for further information on clearfix

EDIT: more background information on the problem http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/

Comment: Thanks for the additional info Cerv!